# how to reload tableview when dismiss the view controller in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

1

I've searched this site and the web and just looking for a simple example on how to reload the root view controller's table view from the detail view. I've tried notifications, setting a tableview in the detailview controller equal to the tableview of the rootview controller...nothing works.

Comment: Do you mean that you are working with SplitVC?

Comment: It depends on how the main and detail controllers are related. Please show your code.

Comment: in first VC class DataManager {

        static let shared = DataManager()
        var firstVC = AdminSupportViewController()

}

Comment: in secondVC      DataManager.shared.firstVC.adminTV.reloadData()

Comment: `AdminSupportViewController()` creates a brand new instance which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. You need a segue or instantiation from the storyboard. And please don't add information in the comments, **edit** your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Closure Callback or NotificationCenter

By NotificationCenter:

**in DetailsViewController**

```
func clickButtonToReloadData(){
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("ReloadDataOfTableView"), object: nil, userInfo: [:])
}
```

**in RootViewController:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadDataOfTableView), name: "ReloadDataOfTableView", object: nil)
}
    
@objc func reloadDataOfTableView(notification : NSNotification){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
    
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {         
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: "ReloadDataOfTableView", object: nil)   
}
```